# How to listen to changes in zoom & contrast/brightness levels in a vtkResliceImageViewer

Tags: c++, windows, event-handling, vtk

I am using `vtkResliceImageViewer` in a C++ code to display DICOM slices. By dragging the left mouse button up/down/left/right, I can change the brightness of the displayed image, which can be seen in the image below. Also, by dragging the right mouse button up/down, I can zoom in/out.

[image]

Is there any way to listen to these changes? Although I have an observer `viewer->AddObserver(vtkCommand::AnyEvent, myCallBack)` for any event, it is still not triggered when the brightness and zoom level are changed using the left/right mouse drag.

```
#include <vtkAutoInit.h>

#define vtkRenderingCore_AUTOINIT 2(vtkRenderingOpenGL2,vtkInteractionStyle)
#define vtkRenderingContext2D_AUTOINIT 2(vtkRenderingContextOpenGL2, vtkRenderingContext2D)

#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>
#include <vtkResliceImageViewer.h>
#include <vtkDICOMImageReader.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkCallbackCommand.h>

void myCallBack(vtkObject* caller, long unsigned int eventId, void* clientData, void* callData)
{
    vtkResliceImageViewer* viewer = static_cast<vtkResliceImageViewer*>(caller);

    double window = viewer->GetColorWindow();
    double level = viewer->GetColorLevel();

    std::cout << "Window: " << window << ", " << "Level: " << level << std::endl;
}

int main(int, char* [])
{
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkDICOMImageReader> reader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkDICOMImageReader>::New();
    reader->SetDirectoryName("C:\\dicoms\\brain");
    reader->Update();

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkResliceImageViewer> viewer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkResliceImageViewer>::New();
    viewer->SetInputData(reader->GetOutput());
    viewer->SetSliceOrientationToXY();
    viewer->SetResliceModeToAxisAligned();

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
    renderWindow->SetSize(800, 600);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
    renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);
    renderWindowInteractor->Initialize();

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkCallbackCommand> callback = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCallbackCommand>::New();
    callback->SetCallback(myCallBack);
    viewer->AddObserver(vtkCommand::AnyEvent, myCallBack);

    viewer->SetupInteractor(renderWindowInteractor);
    viewer->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);
    viewer->Render();
    viewer->GetRenderer()->ResetCamera();
    viewer->GetRenderer()->ResetCameraClippingRange();

    renderWindowInteractor->Start();

    return 0;
}
```

Also, how can I get the current level of contrast/brightness and zoom?